# Finding the perpendicular distance from a chord to the circumference

Tags: geometry, circles, math-history

> Given a circle of circumference 60 and a chord of length 12, what is the perpendicular distance from the chord to the circumference?

What I don't understand about this the distance from the chord to the circumference means geometrically. Wouldn't that vary based on where on the chord you are?

(This question is apparently from BM 85194 (A Babylonian tablet).)

Comment: This is a poorly written question - I believe that the asking was for the maximum perpendicular distance.

Comment: You should make it clear that BM 85194 is a Babylonian tablet.

Comment: @TobyMak fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of the circle,
$C$ be the center of the chord,
and $A$ be one endpoint of the chord.

Then $OCA$ is a right angle
so triangle $OCA$ is a right triangle.

Therefore
$OC^2+CA^2 = OA^2$,
so
$OC = \sqrt{OA^2-CA^2}$.

In this case,
$OA = 60/(2\pi)
=30/\pi$
and
$AC = 12/2 = 6$
so
$OC = \sqrt{(30/\pi)^2-6^2}$.

(added later)

So the distance from
the center of the chord
to the circle
is the radius minus the
distance from the
center of the circle
to the chord or,
in this case,
$30/\pi-\sqrt{(30/\pi)^2-6^2}$.

Comment: I believe I am looking for the distance to the circle, not to the center.

Comment: I added that. It was easy.

Comment: Smart! You make it simple!